# Vector in C++: Why does the outer dimension give EXC_BAD_ACCESS and the inner dimension doesn't?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I have the following code for a vector of vectors of integers (i.e. an integer matrix..)

```
vector<vector<int> > scores (3, vector<int>(2,0));
cout<<scores[1][5];
```

This does not give EXC_BAD_ACCESS,  but this does:

```
cout<<scores[5][1];
```

Why the difference in behavior?

Just to clarify:  This is not specific to the example numbers given. When the inner dimension is out of bounds, there is never an error, not so for the outer!

Comment: You got lucky: `[5][1]` goes outside the area allocated for the vector, but `[1][5]` does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either way, it's undefined behavior to access out-of-bounds.

So anything is allowed to happen. It just "happens" that one case crashes and the other doesn't.

---

As for why exactly the first case does not crash and the second one does in your particular scenario, the first case is mostly just reading past the array into junk heap memory.

But in the second case, you are accessing a bad `vector` object. Since a `vector` object is just a wrapper for a pointer, dereferencing that (bad) pointer upon the second index will crash.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically neither should work, however, `operator[]` is not required to check bounds access (while `at()` is). Thus calling `scores[1][5]` is off into undefined behaviour territory, which in this case unfortunately does not cause a crash. It's just another application of the "undefined behaviour in C/C++ can do just about anything" principle.

Answer (score 0):

If you break the rules, you have no guarantees what will happen. Sometimes it will be one thing and sometimes another. That's why it's important to follow the rules. They're what give you predictable behavior.

If you stay under the speed limit, you never get pulled over for speeding. If you go over the limit, sometimes you get pulled over and sometimes you don't.